# Missing endgroup, undefined control sequence, and missing \cr......But all I did was copy and paste from a table that worked above

Tags: tables, multicolumn, tabu

As the title says I'm getting multiple errors, all I did was copy and paste and edit the entries in my table, but now I'm getting the following errors popping up multiple times each:

! Missing \endgroup inserted.\endgroup \end{tabu},

! Undefined control sequence.\tabu@cellralign ->\tabu@verticalspacing \end{tabu}

! Missing \cr inserted.\cr \end{tabu}

Here are the packages I am using at the moment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
```

Here is the code for the "successful" table:

```
\begin{tabu}{| l | l | l | l |}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{List of Samples by Row} \\
\hline
\hline Sample Number & Entry 1 & Entry 2 & Entry 3 \\
\hline 1 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
\hline 2 & 5 & 4 & 2  \\
\hline 3 & 5 & 4 & 1 \\
\hline 4 & 5 & 3 & 2 \\
\hline 5 & 5 & 3 & 1 \\
\hline 6 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\
\hline 7 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
\hline 8 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
\hline 9 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
\hline 10 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

Here is the code for the "unsuccesful" attempt:

```
\begin{tabu}{| l | l | l | l | l |}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{List of Sample Values & Calculated Sample Means} \\
\hline
\hline Sample Number & Entry 1 & Entry 2 & Entry 3 & Sample Mean \\
\hline 1 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.95 \\
\hline 2 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.33 & 5.80 \\  
\hline 3 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.82 & 5.97 \\ 
\hline 4 & 5.89 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.66 \\
\hline 5 & 5.89 & 5.76 & 5.82 & 5.82 \\
\hline 6 & 5.89 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.68 \\
\hline 7 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.76 \\
\hline 8 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.82 & 5.93 \\
\hline 9 & 6.2 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.78 \\
\hline 10 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.64 \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
```

As you can see nothing really different between the two except an extra column. I did try to paste values in from excel, but I deleted them out and instead entered the data manually, but still getting the same errors. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Remove the `&` in `\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{List of Sample Values & Calculated Sample Means}`, i.e. it needs to become `\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{List of Sample Values Calculated Sample Means}`. (On this site there is also an almost religious support of `booktabs`, so maybe you want to change your confession ... ;-)

Comment: Again done over by a simple important character I forgot to escape. New pair of eyes was useful. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might also want to replace tabu with tabular since you don't use tabu`s X type column anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want to print a `&` in the `multicolumn`, you might want to use `\&` instead of `&` as shown in the following example. I have also replaced `tabu` with `tabular` since you anyways did not use `tabu`'s `X` type column. I also added a second variant using `booktabs` as well as `makecell` and `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l | l |}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{List of Sample Values \& Calculated Sample Means} \\
\hline
\hline Sample Number & Entry 1 & Entry 2 & Entry 3 & Sample Mean \\
\hline 1 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.95 \\
\hline 2 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.33 & 5.80 \\  
\hline 3 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.82 & 5.97 \\ 
\hline 4 & 5.89 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.66 \\
\hline 5 & 5.89 & 5.76 & 5.82 & 5.82 \\
\hline 6 & 5.89 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.68 \\
\hline 7 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.76 \\
\hline 8 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.82 & 5.93 \\
\hline 9 & 6.2 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.78 \\
\hline 10 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.64 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{table}[hb]
\centering
\caption{List of Sample Values \& Calculated Sample Means}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2] *{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
\toprule
{\thead{Sample\\ Number}} & {\thead{Entry 1}} & {\thead{Entry 2}} & {\thead{Entry 3}} & {\thead{Sample\\ Mean}} \\
\midrule
1 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.95 \\
2 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.33 & 5.80 \\  
3 & 5.89 & 6.2 & 5.82 & 5.97 \\ 
4 & 5.89 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.66 \\
5 & 5.89 & 5.76 & 5.82 & 5.82 \\
\addlinespace
6 & 5.89 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.68 \\
7 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.76 \\
8 & 6.2 & 5.76 & 5.82 & 5.93 \\
9 & 6.2 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.78 \\
10 & 5.76 & 5.33 & 5.82 & 5.64 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's very pretty actually. To comment on `tabular` for whatever reason it was not registering on my editor. Perhaps it was other errors that may have messed it up. Thank you for this assistance. Something new I've learned.